# Rollup cli does not exit if I use closeBundle hook in a plugin

Tags: node.js, rollupjs

I am using `rollup` (version 2.56.3) hook `closeBundle()` in a plugin I wrote to postprocess my build using spawn. When I run, `rollup` hangs after the postprocess. It does print `"make done...."`, which indicates the postprocess went fine, but then sits there without returning to the shell prompt. I have to press ^c to get back to shell prompt. Here is the hook function,

```js
function make() {
    return {
        closeBundle() {
            let elMake = require('child_process').spawn('npm', ['run', 'make'], {
                stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
                shell: true
            });
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                elMake.on('error', reject)
                elMake.on('exit', code => {
                    if (code === 0) {
                        console.log("make done....");
                        resolve()
                    } else {
                        const err = new Error(`make exited with code ${code}`)
                        reject(err)
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    };
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

It was happening due to MS typescript compiler bug. After some digging with google search finally found the answer. Read this thread for the details https://giters.com/rollup/rollup/issues/4213. On some platforms this was hanging up rollup.

It has been fixed with TypeScript 4.4.3